# Documentclass user macros

Tags: document-classes, templates, boxes

I wanted to create a documentclass for a [complex template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/creating-a-complex-template). I ran into the following problem:

1. I want to have user macros to store content in boxes which are then displayed by the template in the class code
2. I have to measure those boxes in order to set the dimensions of my layout
3. I would like my layout to be in the document class, and not in the document source file
4. I would like to be able to use user macros for storing the above-mentioned content in my document source file

Is that possible?

As a small example, let's pretend I want to create a frame using `TikZ` which would be big enough to accomodate user provided text . I would want something in the lines of:

documentclass:

```
...
\newsavebox{\titlebox}
\sbox{\titlebox}{\parbox{\5cm}{\UserProvidedText}}

\newlength\titleheight
\settototalheight\titleheight{\usebox{\titlebox}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5cm,\titleheight) {\UserProvidedText};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

document source:

```
%provide \UserProvidedText somehow
```

As I see it, documentclass needs to know about `\UserProvidedText` before the document source is itself read (I am presuming that TeX simply reads documentclass, and then goes on with reading the rest of the source).

Comment: You might want to rephrase your questions, especially 1. You want to have user macros which stores their content in boxes which are then displayed in certain points of the template by the class code, don't you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I think I understand the problem, but we can't tell what challenges you're encountering.  Can you post a minimal example of what you've done so far and the undesired output?  The answer to the question "Is this possible" is usually "Yes, if you do it right;" but that may not be the right question.

Comment: I added a small code snippet with an explanation of what I am troubled with. I lack the knowledge to be able to explain it better without further questions or guidance.

Comment: That's helpful already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document class itself shouldn't produce any output, which is what your `tikzpicture` environment is attempting to do.  One way to get around that is to save that code in an `\AtBeginDocument` command.  For example, here is a class file, which I have named `ipavlic.cls`:

```
\LoadClass{article}
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\AtBeginDocument{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw ([xshift=1cm]current page.west) node[rectangle,text width=5cm,rotate=90]  {\@title};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The `\LoadClass{article}` command makes this class basically a “derived class” of the standard `article.cls`; probably a good idea to not start from scratch. `:D` The article class provides the `\title` command with the exact same functionality that I renewed it to; I just did that to show you what it does.  It saves its input in a macro `\@title` (the `@` sign is a just a convention for class/package-internal macros.  It somewhat protects this text from being overwritten accidentally.)  The `\AtBeginDocument` macro saves its input for execution right after `\begin{document}`.

Note also that it's TikZ *nodes* that contain text, not rectangles.  And you don't need to save the title in a box then put it in a node—TikZ will probably take care of that for you.

Now here is a TeX file using this shiny new class.

```
\documentclass{ipavlic}
\title{TikZ Placement of Title}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

A disadvantage to this implementation is that because it relies on TikZ's `remember picture` mechanism, you have to run LaTeX twice to get the title in the right place.

Another method would be to alter the shipout routines which are executed at the end of every page.  Your custom routine would place all of the rules and extra info outside of the regular type block.  If it were me doing that I would use the `pgfpages` package but there are methods with less overhead I'm sure.

Comment: That's very helpful! I know the basics of TikZ but am calculating box sizes in order to draw a "table" grid (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/creating-a-complex-template). Just to clarify, it is my understanding that `TikZ` needs two runs for remember picture. So if I want to use `TikZ`, I am forced to run it twice. Is that so?

Comment: @ipavlic: That's correct.  Perhaps you can get away with using the anchors that TikZ attaches to its nodes to draw the grid lines.  But in the end you will need to define the size of the type block based on the sizes of all your little nodes--which sounds like a headache to me.  Knock yourself out, but if I were doing this I would fix the grid (maybe relative to the font size) and leave it up to the user to make sure his text fit in the grid.  That's how real-world, paper, templated forms work.