# How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

This is perhaps a simple question with a simple answer, but I'm stumped as a `tikz` novice. What would be the best method to add an image (logo) file to the upper left-hand corner of my document?

[image: sample document with desired result]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I wish to avoid using `fancyhdr` to achieve this result.

Comment: Do you want the image on every page of your document, or only on one?

Comment: Every page would be preferable, but both solutions would be great to see (if anyone is willing/has the time). Sorry, I failed to mention this.

Comment: If you want the image on every page, you can put your TikZ code into the header (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/tikzpicture-on-every-page). If you only need it for a single page, `\tikz [remember picture, overlay] \node at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west] {\includegraphics{...}};` should do the trick.

Comment: You can also find an example similar to what Jake has given in the `pgf` manual on page 200. (version 2.10)

Comment: This does the trick! Do you know if there's any way to eliminate the extra spacing the `\tikz` command generates that forces the text downward by about `\baselineskip`?

Comment: @Caleb: Try putting a `%` at the end of the line containing the TikZ code.

Comment: To follow up @Jake's comment above you may also need to shift the image from the top left corner. To achieve this work with the `shift` option, e.g. `\tikz [remember picture, overlay] \node [shift={(1cm,-1cm)}] at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west] {\includegraphics{...}};`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is powerful, [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) can also be used to perform this via `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` (or `\AddToShipoutPictureFG`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{tiger}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can you include this on one single page? Now it shows up in multiple pages.

Comment: @kexxcream: Use the starred version: `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` or `\..FG*`. Add it to the page of interest and it will be added when the page is shipped out.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [the `background` package](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/background/) which internally relies on `tikz` to place either an imported graphic logo or a logo created with a `tikzpicture` on each page or on selected pages:

[image]

The code below places the image on each page. However, if you only want to place the logo on some of the pages you would simply load the package with the `some` option:

```
 \usepackage[some]{background}
```

and then issue the `\BgThispage` on the pages where you wanted the logo.  An example of including the image on specific pages (ex, 2, 3, and 6) can be found in [Image on top specified page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59285/4301).

### Note

- Need at least two runs to see the logo.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyGraphicLogo}{% For imported graphic logo
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,yshift=-2cm, xshift=2cm]
  \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{foo}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\MyTikzLogo}{% For a logo drawn with TikZ
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,yshift=-1cm, xshift=1cm]
    \draw [cyan,fill=yellow] (0cm,0cm) 
        -- (2cm,  0cm) 
        -- (2cm, -2cm)
        -- (0cm, -2cm)
        -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

%\SetBgContents{\MyGraphicLogo}% Select included image
\SetBgContents{\MyTikzLogo}% Select tikz picture

\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select roation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo


\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer based on the `background` package. Suppose I would like to do exactly the same thing but with the logo placed on the top right corner. I try to set the position as current page.north east. It doesn't seem to work (no picture). May I please know what is the problem in this case?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I think you'll need to adjust the `xshift` to be negative in that case.  If that does not solve your issue, please post a new question.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: or try to play with anchors