# Image on top specified page

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

How can i place an image on the top of the specified page. For example odd pages will be filled by image, even with text. Or, i just want to make sure that (lua)latex will place images on page 2,3,6?

Similar problem was discussed here: [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a version of a solution to [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38754/4301) adapted to only add the specified logo on pages `2,3, and 6`.  It uses the `[some]` option to [the `background` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/background).

To change the pages on which the graphic is placed, you simply need to change the values in the definition of `\ListOfPagesWithLogo`.  With that macro set as:

```
\newcommand*{\ListOfPagesWithLogo}{2,3,6}
```

one obtains the logo on pages `2`, `3`, and `6`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used the `xstring` package for numerical comparisons as I like that syntax but this can be adapted to not require that.
- This version below places a `tikz` picture, but you can un-commented the `\SetBgContents` line if you wish to include an external graphic.
- Two compile runs are required, the first to obtain the coordinates, the second to do the actual drawing.

### Code:

```
% Modified version of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx/38754#38754
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[some]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\MyGraphicLogo}{% For imported graphic logo
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,yshift=-2cm, xshift=2cm]
  \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{foo}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\MyTikzLogo}{% For a logo drawn with TikZ
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,yshift=-1cm, xshift=1cm]
    \draw [cyan,fill=yellow] (0cm,0cm) 
        -- (2cm,  0cm) 
        -- (2cm, -2cm)
        -- (0cm, -2cm)
        -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

%\SetBgContents{\MyGraphicLogo}% Select included image
\SetBgContents{\MyTikzLogo}% Select tikz picture

\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select roation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo

\newcommand*{\ListOfPagesWithLogo}{2,3,6}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AddLogoIfCurrentPageIsOnList}{%
    \foreach \LogoPage in \ListOfPagesWithLogo {%
        \IfEq{\arabic{page}}{\LogoPage}{%
            \bg@material%
            \breakforeach%
        }{}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
\AddEverypageHook{\AddLogoIfCurrentPageIsOnList}%


\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The author/maintainer of **background** package should look at the command `\NoBgThispage` again. As it is now, it can be called only once. The same applies to `\SetBgContents` and associated commands.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You want to AhmedMusa's comment?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a package based on keys. There is no dependence on **background** and **everypage** packages.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{xbackground.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{xbackground}[2012/06/11 v0.0.1 Insert background stuff (AM)]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\RequirePackage{ltxkeys}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\new@def\bgdcond#1\fi{\csname @#1first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname}
\new@def\bgdifx@aux#1#2\bgd@ifx@#3#4\bgd@ifx@@{\ifx#1#3}
\begingroup
\lccode`\&=1 \lccode`\*=2 \catcode`\&=7 \catcode`\*=8
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \new@def\bgdifx#1#2{%
    \csname @\bgdifx@aux#1&\bgd@ifx@#2*\bgd@ifx@@
      first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
  }
  \new@def\bgdifblank#1{%
    \csname @\bgdifx@aux#1&\bgd@ifx@&\bgd@ifx@@
      first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
  }
}
\cptnewvariables{box}[bgd@]{mainbox,tempbox}
\cptnewvariables{if}{bgdbreakfor,bgdlastitem,verbose}
\cptnewvariables{count}{bgdfordepth}
\cptnewvariables{if}[bgd@]{nobackground,allpages,oddpages,evenpages}
\newletcs\bgdbreakfor\bgdbreakfortrue
% Both pgf's \foreach and catoptions' \cptdocommalist are heavy macros.
% Optimosiasts can do with a lighter and nestable \bgdfor. There is a lot
% of iteration on each page.
% \bgdfor[<parser>]<holder-cmd>:={<list>}\do{<callback>}
% \bgdfor*[<parser>]<holder-cmd>:={<listcmd>}\do{<callback>}
\robust@def*\bgdfor{\cpt@teststopt\bgd@for,}
\robust@def\bgd@for[#1]#2:=#3\do#4{%
  \advance\bgdfordepth\@ne
  \edef\bgdforlist{\ifboolTF{cpt@st}\expandcsonce\unexpanded{#3}}%
  \def\getcurrentitem{getcurrentitem@\romannumeral\bgdfordepth}%
  \def\getnextitem{getnextitem@\romannumeral\bgdfordepth}%
  \bgdbreakforfalse\bgdlastitemfalse
  \def\bgdforcount{itemcountonlevel\romannumeral\bgdfordepth}%
  \csn@def\bgdforcount{0}%
  \csn@def\getcurrentitem##1#1{%
    \csn@edef\bgdforcount{\the\numexpr\usename\bgdforcount+1}%
    \bgdifx{##1}\bgdfor{%
      \bgdbreakforfalse\bgdlastitemfalse
    }{%
      \edef#2{\unexpanded{##1}}\usename\getnextitem
    }%
  }%
  \long\csn@def\getnextitem##1#1{%
    \edef\nextitem{\unexpanded{##1}}%
    \bgdifx{##1}\bgdfor{\bgdlastitemtrue\def\nextitem{}}{}%
    #4\relax
    \ifboolTF{bgdbreakfor}{%
      \bgdbreakforfalse\bgdlastitemfalse
      \begingroup
      \csn@def\getcurrentitem####1\bgdfor#1{\endgroup
        \edef\bgdforremainder{\unexpanded{####1}}%
      }%
    }{}%
    \usename\getcurrentitem##1#1%
  }%
  \bgdifx\bgdforlist\@empty{%
    \ifbgdverbose
      \@warning{Empty list passed to \noexpand\bgdfor\on@line}%
    \fi
  }{%
    \cpt@sttrue\cpt@csvnormalize[#1]\bgdforlist
    \expandafter\usename\expandafter\getcurrentitem\bgdforlist#1\bgdfor#1%
  }%
  \advance\bgdfordepth\m@one
}
% I saw a source of spurious space in one of the macros of everypage
% package. So I may well define my own hooks. Also, \AtBeginDocument
% seems too early for these hooks.
\AfterStartOfDocument{%
  \let\bgd@saved@outputpage\@outputpage
  \def\@outputpage{%
    \let\bgd@saved@begindvi\@begindvi
    \def\@begindvi{%
      \bgd@everypage@hook
      \bgd@thispage@hook
      \let\bgd@thispage@hook\relax
      \bgd@saved@begindvi
    }%
    \bgd@saved@outputpage
    \let\@begindvi\bgd@saved@begindvi
  }%
}
\new@def*\bgd@everypage@hook{}
\new@def*\bgd@thispage@hook{}
\robust@def*\AtBeginEveryPage{\g@addto@macro\bgd@everypage@hook}
\robust@def*\AtBeginCurrentPage{\g@addto@macro\bgd@thispage@hook}
\robust@def*\AtBeginNextPage{\afterpage}
\ltxkeys@declarekeys[BGD]{background}[bgd]{%
  bool/verbose/true;
  choice/content.{
      from file/.code=\let\bgd@content\bgd@filecontent,
      tikzpicture/.code=\let\bgd@content\bgd@tikzcontent,
      tikz picture/.code=\let\bgd@content\bgd@tikzcontent,
      tikz background/.code=\let\bgd@content\bgd@tikzcontent,
      use default/.code=\let\bgd@content\bgd@defaultcontent
    }
    /from file;
  cmd/default content/DRAFT/\def\bgd@defaultcontent{#1};
  cmd/position/current page.center/
    \edef\bgd@position{\ltxkeys@stripallouterbraces{#1}};
  cmd/opacity/1.0/\def\bgd@opacity{#1};
  cmd/angle/0/\def\bgd@angle{#1};
  cmd/scale/1/\def\bgd@scale{#1};
  cmd/color/gray!45/\def\bgd@color{#1};
  cmd/xshift/0cm/\def\bgd@hshift{#1};
  cmd/yshift/0cm/\def\bgd@vshift{#1};
  cmd/anchor//\def\bgd@anchor{#1};
  bool/all pages/true/\usename{bgd@allpages#1};
  cmd/pages/1/\edef\bgdpages{\ltxkeys@stripallouterbraces{#1}};
  bool/odd pages/true/\usename{bgd@oddpages#1};
  bool/even pages/true/\usename{bgd@evenpages#1};
  bool/no background/true/\usename{bgd@nobackground#1};
  cmd/graphics width/2cm/\edef\bgdgraphicswidth{#1};
  cmd/graphics height/2cm/\edef\bgdgraphicsheight{#1};
  cmd/graphics file/x/
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \ifblankTF{#1}{%
        \@latexerr{Image file is empty}\@ehd
      }{%
        \edef\bgdgraphicsfile{\ltxkeys@stripallouterbraces{#1}}%
      }
    \fi;
  cmd/viewport/0 5 0 5/
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \ifblankTF{#1}{\@latexerr{'viewport' is empty}\@ehd}{}
    \fi;
  cmd/view port/0 5 0 5/\ltxkeys@setaliaskey{viewport};
  cmd/every picture//\ifltxkeys@dec\else\everybackground{#1}\fi;
  cmd/every background//\ifltxkeys@dec\else\everybackground{#1}\fi;
}
\robust@def*\everybackground#1{\gdef\everybackgroundtoks{#1}}
\everybackground{}
\robust@def*\showeverybackground{%
  \typeout{Every picture settings: \bgd@everybackground}%
}
% To-do:
% \addtoeverybackground, \removefromeverybackground, \emptyeverybackground

% This is for imported graphics. Use the key 'content=from file'.
% It is better and faster to always draw your picture for reuse.
\robust@def*\bgd@filecontent{%
  \cptexpandsecond\includegraphics{[%
    viewport=\bgdviewport,
    width=\bgdgraphicswidth,
    height=\bgdgraphicsheight,
    scale=\bgdscale,% in case you prefer scale.
  ]{\bgdgraphicsfile}}%
}

% This is for new tikz drawings, to be drawn. For a graphics being
% momentarily drawn with tikZ, complete your design in the environment
% 'tikzbackground' and submit 'tikz picture' or 'tikzpicture'
% as the value of key 'content' in \newbackground.
\robust@def*\tikzbackground{\cpt@testopt\bgd@tikzbackground{}}
\robust@def*\bgd@tikzbackground[#1]{%
  \global\setbox\bgd@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
}
\robust@def*\endtikzbackground{%
  \end{tikzpicture}\egroup
  \aftergroup\bgd@tikzb@ckground
}
\robust@def*\bgd@tikzb@ckground{%
  \setbox\bgd@mainbox=\vbox{\unvbox\bgd@mainbox\box\bgd@tempbox}%
  \def\bgd@tikzcontent{\copy\bgd@mainbox}%
}
\robust@def*\bgd@mastercontent{%
  \cptexpandsecond{\begin{tikzpicture}}%
    {[remember picture,overlay,\everybackgroundtoks]}
  \node [rotate=\bgd@angle,scale=\bgd@scale,opacity=\bgd@opacity,%
    xshift=\bgd@hshift,yshift=\bgd@vshift,color=\bgd@color]
    at (\bgd@position)[\bgd@anchor]{\bgd@content};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\new@def*\background@stack{}
\robust@def*\newbackground{\cpt@testpm\bgd@newbackground}
\robust@def*\bgd@newbackground#1{%
  \ifcpt@pm\else
    \edef\background@stack{%
      \ifx\background@stack\@empty\else\expandcsonce\background@stack;\fi
      \unexpanded{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
}
\new@def*\bgddofifo#1{\bgdfifo#1,\bgdfifo,}
\new@def*\bgdfifo#1,{\bgdifx{#1}\bgdfifo{}{\do{#1}\bgdfifo}}
\robust@def*\bgd@putcontent{%
  \bgdfor*[;]\reserveda:=\background@stack\do{%
    \def\do####1{\usename{bgd@####1false}}%
    \bgddofifo{oddpages,evenpages,allpages}%
    \cptexpandargonce{\ltxkeys@setkeys[BGD]{background}}\reserveda
    \ifbgd@nobackground\else
      \ifbgd@allpages
        \bgd@mastercontent
      \else
        \ifbgd@oddpages
          \ifodd\thepage\bgd@mastercontent\fi
        \else
          \ifbgd@evenpages
            \ifodd\thepage\else\bgd@mastercontent\fi
          \else
            \bgdfor*\reservedb:=\bgdpages\do{%
              \ifnum\thepage=\reservedb\relax
                \bgd@mastercontent\bgdbreakfor
              \fi
            }%
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\AtBeginEveryPage{\bgd@putcontent}  
\robust@def*\nobackgroundonthispage{%
  \let\saved@putcontent\bgd@putcontent
  \let\bgd@putcontent\relax
  \afterpage{%
    \let\bgd@putcontent\saved@putcontent
    \let\saved@putcontent\relax
  }%
}

% To-do:
% Include package options
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[final]{book}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xbackground}

% This is the environment for setting your tikz picture to be used as 
% the background. See the note above about the environment 'tikzbackground'.
\begin{tikzbackground}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw [cyan,fill=yellow]
  (0cm,0cm)--(2cm,0cm)--(2cm,-2cm)--(0cm,-2cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzbackground}

% User command call with keys. This is where the user gives the background specs.
% The odd details don't concern him/her. You need 2 runs at first use of keys,
% ie, if you change the current value of a key, you may need to compile the
% file twice. Use the 'odd pages' or 'even pages' options to get graphics on
% only odd or even pages. If none of these is given, and 'pages' is also not
% specified, the logo will appear on the first page only. You can decide
% not to insert any graphics at all. You do this by specifying the option
% 'no background'.

% A prime (') on \newbackground means 'ignore this background':
\newbackground'{rubbish}% ignored

% Page 1 gets 2 background pictures:
\newbackground{
  xshift=12cm, yshift=-15cm, anchor=below,
  position=current page.north west, content=tikz picture,
  viewport=20 21 590 400, opacity=1, angle=0.0, scale=.8, % even pages,
  graphics file={./Graphics/comet1}, %no background
  pages=1
}

\newbackground{
  xshift=2.cm, yshift=-2cm, anchor=below,
  position=current page.north west, content=from file,
  viewport=20 21 590 400, opacity=1, angle=0.0, scale=.8, % even pages,
  pages={1,4,5}, graphics file={./Graphics/comet1}, %no background
}

\newbackground{
  xshift=1cm, yshift=-2cm, anchor=below,
  position=current page.north west, content=tikz picture,
  viewport=20 21 590 400, opacity=1, angle=0.0, scale=.8, % even pages,
  pages={2,3,6,8}, graphics file={./Graphics/comet1}, %no background
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}

% \nobackgroundonthispage % try this command

\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. I would recommend you add the `[demo]` option to the `graphicx` package so that others without the specific image file can run the MWE via cut and paste.

Comment: `[demo]` added.