# Collecting tikZ drawings in a box

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please is it possible to collect tikz picture in the following way? I get `\box40=\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0 []`. I would even prefer a `\vbox`, but I get a worse outcome.

```
\makeatletter
\newbox\tempbox
\newbox\mainbox
\def\collecttikzpicture{\@testopt\@collecttikzpicture{}}
\def\@collecttikzpicture[#1]{%
  \global\setbox\tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
}
\def\endcollecttikzpicture{%
  \end{tikzpicture}\egroup
  \setbox\mainbox=\hbox{\unhbox\mainbox\unhbox\tempbox}%
}

\begin{collecttikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw [cyan,fill=yellow]
  (0cm,0cm)--(2cm,0cm)--(2cm,-2cm)--(0cm,-2cm)--cycle;
\end{collecttikzpicture}

\showbox\mainbox
\makeatother
```

Comment: The code for `\endcollect...` runs _inside_ the group for your `collecttikzpicture` environment so as you made a local setting of `\mainbox` it is not set outside the group. Perhaps you just need `\global` but I'm note sure what teh code is intended to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to collect your main box outside the environment group:

```
\def\endcollecttikzpicture{%
  \end{tikzpicture}\egroup
  \aftergroup\collectbox
}

\def\collectbox{\setbox\mainbox=\hbox{\unhbox\mainbox\unhbox\tempbox}}
```

Note, that this makes the `\mainbox` contain the picture, it still has zero size because of the overlay option passed to the tikzpicture. If you remove that the box attains the natural dimensions of the square.

---

As you said you would prefer a vbox:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\newbox\tempbox
\newbox\mainbox
\def\collecttikzpicture{\@testopt\@collecttikzpicture{}}
\def\@collecttikzpicture[#1]{%
  \global\setbox\tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
}
\def\endcollecttikzpicture{%
  \end{tikzpicture}\egroup
  \aftergroup\collectbox
}

\def\collectbox{\setbox\mainbox=\vbox{\unvbox\mainbox\box\tempbox}}
\makeatother


\begin{collecttikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw [cyan,fill=yellow]
  (0cm,0cm)--(2cm,0cm)--(2cm,-2cm)--(0cm,-2cm)--cycle;
\end{collecttikzpicture}



\begin{collecttikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw [cyan,fill=blue]
  (0cm,0cm)--(2cm,0cm)--(2cm,-2cm)--(0cm,-2cm)--cycle;
\end{collecttikzpicture}




\begin{collecttikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw [cyan,fill=green]
  (0cm,0cm)--(2cm,0cm)--(2cm,-2cm)--(0cm,-2cm)--cycle;
\end{collecttikzpicture}




[[[\box\mainbox]]]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed it for the **xbackground** package at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59283/image-on-top-specified-page. Now I can replace the collector command with a box. The box will be faster: once evaluated, it can be inserted on desired pages.

Comment: What is explanation that `\setbox\mainbox=\vbox{\unvbox\mainbox\unhbox\tempbox}` is impossible? Is it due to incompatible boxes or `\@nodocument`?

Comment: yes if you previously collected mainbox as a vbox you can't unhbox it. What were you trying to do?