# What is the advantage of using \@testopt?

Tags: best-practices, programming

I discovered recently `\@testopt` in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59639/collecting-tikz-drawings-in-a-box). I tried to understand the goal with the use of this macro, but in my research I discovered other macros like `\@protected@testopt` and even new packages like `exp-testopt`. Actually, I develop only with TeX and LaTeX2e, what do you think of this macro?

What is the most reliable method?

Comment: +1, plus, to be honest, I wonder how to use it to define macros with larger number of _obligatory_ `{}` arguments (I mean is there any difference in usage?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are at least a couple of reasons for the the existence of `\@testopt`.

If you look at the definition of `\@testopt`, you will see that it is

```
> \@testopt=\long macro:
#1#2->\kernel@ifnextchar [{#1}{#1[{#2}]}.
```

This uses `\kernel@ifnextchar` rather than `\@ifnextchar`: the later may get redefined by for example the AMS math material, whereas `\kernel@ifnextchar` is 'frozen' and should never be redefined. Thus `\@testopt` will always show the same behaviour, searching for `[` and skipping spaces. In that sense, there is a reliability gain from using it rather than coding the test yourself.

The other factor here is token usage. `\@testopt` is one token, whereas doing the test manually requires four tokens (`\kernel@ifnextchar`, `[` and the `[...]` pair). When LaTeX2e was released, that reduction in token usage was important: there are lots of places in the kernel where such alterations were made to keep the size down. Of course, today that is not at all significant.

Answer (score 12):

There's no advantage in using directly `\@testopt`, in my opinion. The question you refer to has

```
\def\collecttikzpicture{\@testopt\@collecttikzpicture{}}
\def\@collecttikzpicture[#1]{%
  \global\setbox\tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
}
```

that is functionally equivalent to

```
\newcommand\collecttikzpicture[1][]{%
  \global\setbox\tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
}
```

and has the advantage of being robust, that is it eventually expands to itself when used in moving arguments, which is *not* the case for the former definition.

With the latter definition, the expansion of `\collecttikzpicture` will be

```
\@protected@testopt \collecttikzpicture \\collecttikzpicture {}
```

where the third token is a peculiar control sequence with a backslash in its name, which has the same office as `\@collecttikzpicture` in the previous definition. So you don't even have to worry about defining an auxiliary control sequence for the real action, because `\newcommand` will take care of that automatically. When `\@protected@testopt` is expanded, it uses `\@testopt`, so `\kernel@ifnextchar` (and not `\@ifnextchar`).

---

Defining a command having mandatory arguments with `\@testopt` is really easy:

```
\def\foo{\@testopt\@foo{DEFAULT}}
\def\@foo[#1]#2#3{Something with #1, #2, #3}
```

Let's see why following the expansion of `\foo{X}{Y}` and `\foo[A]{X}{Y}`. Here's the first one:

```
\foo{X}{Y}
\@testopt\@foo{DEFAULT}{X}{Y}
\kernel@ifnextchar [{\@foo}{\@foo[{DEFAULT}]}{X}{Y}
\@foo[{DEFAULT}]{X}{Y}
Something with DEFAULT, X, Y
```

Here's the second:

```
\foo[A]{X}{Y}
\@testopt\@foo{DEFAULT}[A]{X}{Y}
\kernel@ifnextchar [{\@foo}{\@foo[{DEFAULT}]}[A]{X}{Y}
\@foo[A]{X}{Y}
Something with A, X, Y
```

But, of course,

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3][1]{Something with #1, #2 and #3}
```

is easier *and* robust.

Answer (score 11):

It's probably also relevant here that `\@testopt` came from LaTeX2.09 so originally all LaTeX commands using optional arguments were explicitly defined using it.

The syntactic extension to `\newcommand` and friends to allow the declaration of commands using optional arguments is a more recent (latex2e) addition. They use `\@testopt` internally, but as @Joseph says, using the higher level forms saves some tokens and adds robustness.

Comment: Where "more recent" means it's from 1994 instead of 1986. `:-)`