# Position watermark neatly at the bottom of the page

Tags: positioning, watermark

I use the `draftwatermark` package to show some drafting information at the bottom of each page (the draft infos are included via `svn-multi` macros, but I just inserted text in this MWE for simplicity). As `draftwatermark` does not offer an option to position text, I simply redefine the the origin of the page from where the mark is drawn (from `-1in` to `330pt`).

This works, but it is definitely not the most elegant solution, as it is dependent on font size, page dimensions etc. Ideally I would like to have something that always puts the bottom edge of the watermark around 10pt above the lower end of the page. Can this be done?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sc@wm@print[1]{% redefine positioning of mark (-1in to 330pt)
 \if@sc@wm@stamp
          \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox to \z@{%
            \vskip 330pt \moveleft 1in \vbox{%
              \hbox to \z@{%
                #1\hss}}\vss}
          \dp\@tempboxa\z@
          \box\@tempboxa
          \fi}
\makeatother

\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkColor{black}
\SetWatermarkFontSize{10pt}

\SetWatermarkText{%
    \begin{minipage}{21cm}\centering
    Draft [Revision 269] 30-06-2012 at 07:41:41
    (c) Me, Myself and I \\
    http://127.0.0.1:9800/research/chapter1.tex
    \end{minipage}
        }


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you required to use [`draftwatermark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark), or are other options available/open to you?

Comment: @Werner I could use other "watermark" packages, but I can't use anything that alters (or uses) the footer or the header.

Comment: See *xbackground* package at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59283/image-on-top-specified-page/59511#59511.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an option using the [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic-pkg):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{% Add picture to background of every page
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{3\baselineskip}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\begin{minipage}{21cm}\centering
      Draft [Revision 269] 30-06-2012 at 07:41:41
      \copyright\ Me, Myself and I \\
      \url{http://127.0.0.1:9800/research/chapter1.tex}
    \end{minipage}}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Similar solutions are available using a myriad of packages, including [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`background`](http://ctan.org/pkg/background), to name two, none of which would affect textual content. That is, they all allow for placement of (random) content in the background or foreground.

Comment: Thank you, very nice. I prefer using `\raisebox{15pt}` instead of `{3\baselineskip}` as the baselineskip can vary across pages. Also a `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}` can be useful inside the minipage to ensure that the plotted text looks the same on all pages.