# Image in the top of a page

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I am trying to fix an image in the top of a page, according with the margins definitions.
It is the logo of a conference paper, so it has to be in the head of the first page.
How can i do it?
Thank you for your attention!

Nicolo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So it's just the first page, not all pages? Could http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44169/how-to-place-an-image-at-the-right-top-of-a-document/44183#44183 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59285/586 be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Respect to tcassanelli's answer, note that you can define more of one header style and change among them.

To make  a new style:

```
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{% 
  %definition here
 }
```

To use the above style only in the actual page:

```
\thispagestyle{mystyle}
```

But if you want only a logo in the first page, another option could be the `wallpaper` package. In this way the logo do not take space, so the  position of any other object in the document remain unchanged. A minimal working example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,latin]{article} 
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\title{Minimum exemplum laborandi}
\author{Franciscus Studiosum Somniantis} 

\begin{document}

\addtolength{\wpXoffset}{-7cm} 
\addtolength{\wpYoffset}{12cm} 
\ThisCenterWallPaper{.15}{logo}

\maketitle 

\section{Introductio} 
\lipsum[1]
\section{Materia et modos} 
\lipsum[2] 
\section{Consequitur} 
\lipsum[3]
\section{Disputatio} 
\lipsum[4] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Fancy package?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead[L]{}%\leftmark
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics{image}}%You could place here the image. 
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need it just for the first page and without the black line under the image.

Comment: Besides, the following text is overlying on the logo

Comment: the back line is easily remove by
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

Comment: or you could use \rhead{} for the next pages.

Answer (score 0):

With the following:

```
    \fancypagestyle{mystyle}{% 
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{fancy} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and                               footers
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \fancyhead[L]{}%\leftmark
   \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics{logo}}%You could place here the image. 
   }
```

the head is fine, the problem is the bottom part of the text that doesn't respect the margins.
I defined them in this way:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
```