# Insert image in the header

Tags: graphics, header-footer, lyx

I am a real beginner in LyX and I want to insert a small image into the header. Actually I want to insert two images. But let's begin by one. I have no idea how to do this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the Lyx help file Extented Features, see section 3.5 on Fancy Headers and Footers for the code which will allow you to insert an image into the header.

Probably this link would be helpful for you:

[How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx)