# Margins of a Logo Picture

Tags: graphics, margins

I want to place my university logo at a certain distance from the top-left margins of the page. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For all pages?

Comment: You can take a look at `tikz-page`: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-page?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the red rectangle as being the needed logo.  The solution below is based on TikZ.  Some comments concerning the code:

1. The command for the logo is `\inclkudelogo`.  To appear on the first page it is invoked after the title.  To appear on the others it is invoked in the fancy headings.
2. "The logo" is a node with empty content in my file.  If your logo is the file `logo.jpg` let's say, you can use it through an `\includegraphics[height=...,width=...]{logo}` command in the node's content.
3. `\usepackage{showframe}` is there to make the page layout explicit.
4. The important options in the TikZ environment are `remember picture` and `overlay`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={160mm, 240mm}, left=25mm, top=30mm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\insertlogo}
\rhead{some header}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\insertlogo}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path (current page.north west)
    node[draw, fill, red, inner sep=3ex, text width=6ex,
    below right=2ex] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\title{Document with logo using TikZ}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\insertlogo

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2-8]

\end{document}
```

See also @Peter Grill answer [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx?noredirect=1&lq=1) which uses `background` library.