# How to create this document template

Tags: header-footer, layout, examdesign

I want to use this as a template for a report, but I have no idea where to begin. The first page looks like this, with a gray header, the title in white and the company logo on the right. On the left of the page is a green bar with the name of the division at the bottom.

[image]

From the second page on, the header of the document looks like this, with the main title on the left and the date on the right.

[image]

I would appreciate any help or if you could point me to some resources where I can learn how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at the template for https://www.uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2224. The textpos package should be helpful for the green bar

Comment: For the gray headers see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518841/background-color-in-titlesec

Comment: Thank you, thats really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I couldn't figure out from your question if the green rectangle must appear on the other pages.  If this is the case uncomment the command `\lhead{\greenRectangle}` in the preamble.

For more comments concerning the code see my answer at [Margins of a Logo Picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561518/margins-of-a-logo-picture/561549#561549).

The code that produces the pdf above:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={155mm, 255mm}, left=48mm, top=20mm}

%%% fonts
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\def\footrulewidth{0pt}                           
\def\headrulewidth{0pt}
%%% uncomment the line below if the green rectangle is needed on all pages
% \lhead{\greenRectangle}
\rhead{\grayRectangle}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\definecolor{aGreen}{RGB}{0, 159, 104}
\newcommand{\greenRectangle}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[aGreen] ($(current page.north west)+(3ex, -2ex)$)
    rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(43mm, 2ex)$);
    \path ($(current page.south west)+(3ex, 8ex)$)
    node[white, text width=40mm, align=left, below right, scale=.9]
    {\itshape{Direcci\'on de \\Estudias Econ\'omicos}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\grayRectangle}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[gray!60] ($(current page.north west)+(3ex, -3ex)$)
    rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-3ex, -7ex)$);
    \path ($(current page.north west)+(3ex, -6.5ex)$)
    node[white, above right, scale=.9]
    {\itshape{Industria Manufacturera}};
    \path ($(current page.north east)+(-3.1ex, -6.5ex)$)
    node[white, above left, scale=.9]
    {\itshape{Abril 2020}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%%% tmp packages
% \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\titlepage
\greenRectangle

%%% title
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[use as bounding box] (0, 0) rectangle +(15, .1);
  \draw[ultra thick, fill=gray!65] (-5.3, .7)
  rectangle
  node[pos=.85, fill=blue, below right, inner sep=2.2ex, text width=9ex] {}
  +(20.6, 1.3);
  \path (-1.2, .7) node[above right, text=white, scale=2]
  {\itshape\textbf{Industria Manufacturera}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{ABRIL 2020}

\lipsum[1, 2-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!