# Can I put a logo in the header of a twoside document?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, double-sided, scrpage2

I would like to include a graphics file with a logo in the header of all pages of a twoside document (left and right side). The logo should be left-justified on the left side and right-justified on the right side. The header line and the document title should begin beside the logo. There are two 2 Problems:

- Moving the beginning of header line and document title a litte to the right (left side) and left (right side) to create space for the logo
- Include the logo

Do you have any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[
   12pt,               
   a4paper,             
   twoside,                         
   headinclude,         
   headsepline,                 
   BCOR12mm,                        
   DIV12,               
   openright,             
   bibliography=totoc,            
   listof=totoc,                
   numbers=noenddot,
   fleqn,               
        ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}        
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}                     
\definecolor{grey} {RGB} {132,130,132}

\usepackage{scrpage2}             

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{grey}{\normalfont\sffamily}}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\color{grey}{\normalfont\sffamily}}
\setheadsepline{1pt}[\color{grey}]

\clearscrheadfoot                                                       
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\rehead[ ]{Document title}              
\lohead[ ]{Document title}              
\lehead[ ]{\headmark}                   
\rohead[ ]{\headmark}                        
\refoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}     
\lofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}     

\begin{document}

\section{section title}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Thank your for your comments and answers. I have already tried the above solution (just including the graphics), but was not happy with the result because:

- the line is also unter the logo
- document title and section title have different heights

This time I include a layout draft (the picture in the layout is a substitute for the logo). The measurements of the final logo will be: height=15 mm, width=20 mm (or 79x61 pixel).

[image]

The Document title is "Yaacomo". In the header there should be no text and no line under the logo.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the logo or otherwise say something about the image dimensions? I would include it into `\rehead` resp. `\lohead`, but very likely the headheight must be enlarged.

Comment: Related Question: [Place a TikZ picture on every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41382/place-a-tikz-picture-on-every-page/). You can use `\ifoddpage` to adjust the location of the logo depending on which type of page you are on.

Answer (score 7):

A first try can be to include package `graphicx` for macro `\includegraphics` and change your configuration for the header to:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % for macro \includegraphics
\rehead[ ]{Document title \includegraphics[height=8mm]{example-image-A.jpg}}              
\lohead[ ]{\includegraphics[height=8mm]{example-image-A.jpg} Document title}
```

Btw: `example-image-A.jpg` is part of the package [`MWE`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe), very useful for building MWEs ...

Comment: Exactly my intention, cf. my comment under the question.

Comment: See my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

I added the packages `graphicx` for image inclusion, `calc` to be able to do some calculation, and `adjustbox` for adding some margin, which is needed, because otherwise the headsepline would touch the logo.

I defined some lengthes; see under `%Logo`, perhaps you want to change them. This is also the place for your actual logo.

The head itself is now only in `\cehead` resp. `\cohead`. So it is ensured, that everything is in the same line.

All together, the package `blindtext` is only for, ehem, blindtext (`\Blinddocument` here):

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4, % it's the default anyway
  fontsize=12pt,
  twoside,
  headinclude,
  headsepline,
  BCOR=12mm,
  DIV=12,
  openright,
  bibliography=totoc,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,
  fleqn,
  ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext} % provides blindtext with sectioning

\usepackage{calc} % for some calculation

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey} {RGB} {132,130,132}

\usepackage{graphicx}% for loading images
\usepackage[calc]{adjustbox} % we need some margin around the logo, for option see manual

% Logo
\newlength{\logoheight}\setlength{\logoheight}{15mm} % Adjust height of logo here
\newlength{\logowidth}\setlength{\logowidth}{20mm} % Adjust width of logo here

\newcommand*{\logo}{\raisebox{-5pt}% The bigger the amount of the negative number the more the header is raised!
{\includegraphics[height=\logoheight,width=\logowidth]{example-image-4x3.png}}}

\newlength{\extramargin}\setlength{\extramargin}{5pt} % Change to your needs

\setlength{\headheight}{\logoheight}
% This won't work (!!!):
%%% \KOMAoptions{headheight=\logoheight}

\usepackage{scrpage2}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{grey}{\normalfont\sffamily}}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\color{grey}{\normalfont\sffamily}}
\setheadsepline{1pt}[\color{grey}]

\setheadwidth[\logowidth+\extramargin]{\textwidth-\logowidth-\extramargin} % for calculation "calc" is needed

\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\rehead[]{Yaacomo}
\cehead[]{\headmark\hfill Yaacomo \rlap{\adjustbox{margin={\extramargin} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\logo}}}
%\lohead[]{Yaacomo}
\cohead[]{\llap{\adjustbox{margin=0pt 0pt {\extramargin} 0pt}{\logo}}\ Yaacomo\hfill\headmark}
%\lehead[]{\headmark}
%\rohead[]{\headmark}
\refoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image: appearance]