# esopic and repeating part of document

Tags: xetex, datatool, eso-pic

This answer nicely illustrate the use of eso-pic to repeat part of document.
[Repeating part of document on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147376/repeating-part-of-document-on-every-page)

But when the text entered is large, it is cut-off from the page. It possibly converts it to image and put it in foreground. But this solution fails to work when the length off user input is variable.  Is there any other solution?

Comment: Could you clarify this, please? Exactly where do you want the repeated text? Is your text too wide or too high? If you add an example code that reproduces your problem it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified a little the code in my previous answer introducing a `tabular`.

Can this be OK?
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example
\usepackage[headsep=3cm,top=5cm]{geometry}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \makebox(420,75)[lt]{%
      \footnotesize%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}*{3}{p{4.5cm}}@{}}%
      \textbf{Author}\newline\myauthor&%
      \textbf{Date of birth}\newline\mydate&%
      \textbf{Address}\newline\myaddress%
      \end{tabular}%
}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\myauthor}{user34083}
\newcommand{\mydate}{December 26, 1997}
\newcommand{\myaddress}{26 Washington Ave., Manhattan, New York.\newline United States of America}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument % just for the example

\end{document}
```