# boxing the entire page

Tags: spacing, positioning

Sorry if you don't understand me, but English is not my native language.

Is it possible to put a frame at `x cm` from the right and left edges of the page and at `y cm` from the up and bottom edges of the page?

like in this image.
[image]

I have tried with the `showframe` package and the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package, but none of those works for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows what you have tried.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem which works for your particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of [Place a TikZ picture on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41390/4301):

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.

## Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\newcommand*{\VOffset}{2cm}% vertical offset
\newcommand*{\HOffset}{1cm}% horizontal offset

\newcommand{\MyTikzLogo}{% For a logo drawn with TikZ
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,draw=black,ultra thick]
    \draw [gray] ($(\HOffset,-\paperheight+\VOffset)$) rectangle (\paperwidth-\HOffset,-\VOffset);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\SetBgContents{\MyTikzLogo}% Set tikz picture

\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select roation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo

\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that ensures frames on every page, with the `typogrid`,`geometry` and `framed` package, with `\FrameRule` set to 0pt. One has to make titles by hand, as `\maketitle` creates empty (framed) pages before the title. The `framed` environment is used only to have a small space between text and frame.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin = \dimexpr 2.5cm + \fboxrule\relax, vmargin =\dimexpr 3cm + \fboxrule\relax]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft, columns = 1,margin = false, headings = false]{typogrid}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum, titling}
\title{Some Title}
\author{I. Myself}
\setlength\FrameRule{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\begin{center}
\Huge Some Title\\[2ex]
\Large I. Myself \\[4\baselineskip]
\end{center}

\section{A First Section}
 \lipsum[1-4]
 \end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]